# protobuf-maven-plugin compile to golang

Tags: maven, go, protocol-buffers

I need to generate source files from the same .proto file to both Java and Go (golang).
The `protobuf-maven-plugin` has the `compile` goal for Java, but no `compile-go` goal for golang.

Any idea how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is [special plugin for maven](https://github.com/raydac/mvn-golang) to work with golang, so that it can be used in maven project infrastructure with Java, I made some example of "how to" [generate Go from protobuf scripts in maven](https://github.com/raydac/mvn-golang/tree/master/mvn-golang-examples/mvn-golang-example-protobuf)